# CS CART: Under product blocks -> content is it possible to add options under filling dropdown option?

Tags: php, cs-cart

If I choose a specific layout in my backend and I add a product block, under content menu of this block theres a filling dropdown options(manually, newest,recently viewed...) is it possible to add another option to the filling dropdown option? let say cheapest product? If its possible what file directory will i modify?

Answer (score 0):

All filling types are located in schema in the following file:

app/schemas/block_manager/fillings.php

Fillings and their additional parameters are assigned to the objects (products, categories, banners, etc) in the following file:

app/schemas/block_manager/blocks.php

E.g.

```
'products' => array(
    'content' => array(
        'items' => array(
            ....
            'fillings' => array(
                'manually' => array(
                    'picker' => 'pickers/products/picker.tpl',
                    'picker_params' => array(
                        'type' => 'links',
                    ),
                ),
                'newest' => array(
                    'params' => array(
                        'sort_by' => 'timestamp',
                        'sort_order' => 'desc',
                        'request' => array(
                            'cid' => '%CATEGORY_ID%'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'recent_products' => array(
                    'params' => array(
                        'apply_limit' => true,
                        'session' => array(
                            'pid' => '%RECENTLY_VIEWED_PRODUCTS%'
                        ),
                        'request' => array(
                            'exclude_pid' => '%PRODUCT_ID%'
                        ),
                        'force_get_by_ids' => true,
                    ),
                ),
                'most_popular' => array(
                    'params' => array(
                        'popularity_from' => 1,
                        'sort_by' => 'popularity',
                        'sort_order' => 'desc',
                        'request' => array(
                            'cid' => '%CATEGORY_ID'
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

You can extend schemas with the My changes module. As example, you can use the built-in Bestsellers module:

app/addons/bestsellers/schemas/block_manager/blocks.post.php
app/addons/bestsellers/schemas/block_manager/fillings.post.php

Hope this will help